# Fatal error:Call to a member function getSource()on a non-object in\app\cose\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php on line1389

Tags: magento

I am getting following error on list.phtml page on my local instance of a site under development--->

```
Fatal error: Call to amember function getSource() on a  non-object in 
D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php on line 1389
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a  non-object in 
\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php on line 1389
```

I was getting this error because some of the attributes were not created in Admin panel.
But using `$_product->getAttributeText('preferred')` values were being fetched in list.phtml.

When I created these attribute and assigned those to default attribute set problem solved.

Comment: Confirmed, I had the same error. I had created product attributes on my live store and not my dev store. Creating attributes and assigning them to the appropriate attribute group fixed the issue.

Comment: This worked for me also. In my case also 2 attributes were missing.

Comment: If you want to test to see if a product has given attribute defined use $product->getAttribute() which doesn't throw an error like $product->getAttributeText() does.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved my time.

Answer (score 6):

Find the following code

```
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()
        ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getSource()
                ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
}
```

and replace with

```
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    if ($attribute = $this->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)) {
        return
                $attribute->getSource()
                            ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
    } else {
        //Mage::log(\'attributes-errors.log\',$attributeCode);
        return false; 
    }
}
```

source: http://www.ubertheme.com/question/solving-error-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getsource/

Answer (score 0):

Please get more tips
How attribute is complete

> When I created these attribute and assigned tem to default attribute set problem solved.